# IF en select de MS SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

necesito hacer un select con un IF para que me devuelva un booleano

Antes esta consulta estaba en MySql y ahí el if funcionaba pero aquí no encuentro la manera.

Quiero hacer algo como esto (codigo que no funciona actualmente):

```
SELECT 
 IF (factura != '' AND year(fecha) = 2019) 
  true 
 ELSE 
  false 
 as check FROM [DB01].dbo.tablaalb;
```

En mysql era así:

```
SELECT IF(factura != ''  and year(fecha) = 2019,true,false) as check
```

y en mysql funciona, pero en sql server no veo la manera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo veo se podría hacer así:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN factura != '' AND year(fecha) = 2019
        THEN true
        ELSE false
    END AS check
FROM ...
```

o

```
SELECT 
    IF factura != '' AND year(fecha) = 2019
        RETURN true
    ELSE 
        RETURN FALSE
    END AS check
FROM ...
```

o

```
SELECT 
    IIF (factura != '' AND year(fecha) = 2019, true, false) AS check
FROM ...
```

pero no tengo SQL Server y no puedo probar ninguno :-(

Ya nos contarás.

Comment: La primera y la tercera opciones son casi válidas. La segunda está completamente mal. En SQL Server no hay tipo de dato booleano, lo más parecido es el bit que acepta 1 y 0.